# Ebay html special tags not working?

Tags: html

`{ eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" }` this tag will display all items of my store in grid view but it is not working when I use in my store. No error will be displayed.

Am I missing something? Please suggest how to do customize store pages in ebay.

Comment: Please provide more detail. Show some of the page where that tag is used. Tell us what you mean by "it is not working", etc.

Comment: above store tags will not display any of my items list . it display as it is like { eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" } code will display in ebay page.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have spaces in there:

```
{ eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" }
```

Try this:

```
{eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1"}
```

See also: the [Special Tags](https://web.archive.org/web/20180416203832/http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/specialtysites/stores-specific-tags.html) help topic on eBay

- 0 - List view
- 1 - Gallery view

Does that work..?

Answer (score 0):

In any html editor, when you try to copy the code and directly paste it in the design view, the editor changes the source code and converts some special characters.

For example,

```
{eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" SIZE="15"} will be changed to {eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY=&quot;1&quot; SIZE=&quot;15&quot;}
```

Or

```
 eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY="1" } to {eBayStoresItemList DISPLAY=&quot;1&quot; }
```

This is because the editor automatically converts double quotes and inserts the html code for it.

**The solution:**

Go to the code view of your html, or try to open it with notepad and copy/paste the oraginal code exactly as it is.

Good luck.